# Unauthorized Access Exception - Access to the Path Denied while copying file to other Directory in C#

Tags: c#, file, directory

I got an error while copying file from 1 folder to another folder in c#.
Here is the code:

```
string xFilename = Path.GetDirectoryName(fdlg.FileName.ToString());    
string yPath = Path.GetFileName(fdlg.FileName.ToString());    
upload_label.Text = xFilename + "\\" + yPath;    
string zFilePath = xFilename + "\\" + yPath;
Directory.CreateDirectory("test");

try 
{
    File.Copy(zFilePath, "\\test", true);
} 
catch(Exception eeee) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(eeee + "");
    throw;
}
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Get access to the folder?

Comment: Please do a favor to yourself...rename that variables to something meaningful...

Comment: okay. i will rename it. sorry

Answer (score 1):

MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx) says that `File.Copy` throws the `UnauthorizedAccessException` when

> The caller does not have the required permission.
>
> -or-
>
> destFileName is read-only.

Please check the above conditions and try again.

Comment: so, is there an alternative way other than File.Copy?

Comment: @user3541736 if you do not have rights...you do not have rights. dot. whatever you do to copy. BTW you didn't say where it fails (it may even be CreateDirectory). 2nd: you create directory with relative path but you access with absolute path.

Comment: Well, before looking for an alternative you should understand what went wrong, because the framework is helping you out here by throwing an exception and it shows only 2 reasons for doing so. Do you have permissions to write in the directory that you are writing to? Have you checked whether the file that is already present there with the same name is read only or not? Have you tried removing that file and then trying? Verify your paths.

Comment: My File.Copy failed because there was already that file at the destination.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the subcontents if you have those, like in my case.

This is what i did, maybe you can try these steps:

1.) remove first the contents by removing files and folders on that path.

2.) then remove the folder itself after it is empty.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("YourPath");

//delete files
foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}

//delete folders
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}

//then delete the path itself after it is empty
Directory.Delete(path);
```